# Convert "emailAdress=<email-address>" found in Subject field of x.509 SSL certificate to hexadecimal

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509, asn.1, der

I have a **'Subject'** of SSL x.509 certificate given as

```
Subject:    C=XX, ST=XX, L=XX, O=XX, OU=XX, emailAddress=admin@adobe.pw, CN=trustasia.asia
```

and I want to covert this to binary stream as found in SSL certificate when it is sent on wire, I know definition Subject field is given in [RFC-5280](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf) in ASN.1 notation and DER encoding rules given in [x.609](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf) are to covert this field to binary representation, these two documents and with little help from [code](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-checkins/X_rp9vyc-70)(which gave hexadecimal representations of OID such as **id-at-countryName:2.5.4.6:{0x55, 0x04, 0x06}**) i was able to covert all the RDNs(**RelativeDistinguishedNames**) to their binary representation, but I am stuck with **emailAdress** filds.
I found its **OID:1.2.840.113549.1.9.1** but don't know what it is hexadecimal representation.

Can you please guide me how can I covert this to binary representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are talking about OID encoding using ASN.1 Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER). I would suggest to check this article to get detailed information about OBJECT_IDENTIFIER encoding rules: [OBJECT IDENTIFIER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540809(v=vs.85).aspx)

OID string value conversion to ASN.1 DER will result in:

`06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 09 01`

where, 0x06 -- is OBJECT_IDENTIFIER tag identifer, 0x09 -- encoded OID value length in bytes, the rest bytes (`2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 09 01`) represent OID binary form

Comment: Your suspicion is right, , Thanks man :)
I am new to SSL and Crypto you guided me in right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

emailAddress is of type IA5String so it would appear in the certificate in the same form as shown in subject line: 'admin@adobe.pw'.